# HTML element DIV disappears in Chrome launched by Selenium

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, google-chrome

I have SPA (single page application) written using **Backbone** + **jQuery** and some automation tests (**Selenium**) and when some of the tests are running they start failing because of a **DIV** element disappears itself. It disappears just after the last AJAX call is finished.

I cannot find the reasons of disappearing. Does probably someone know what could it be?

The issue is **only under Chrome launched by Selenium**.

1. I tried to refresh the page in Selenium Chrome - The issue is still here.
2. I tried to disable all installed plugins (including Selenium plugin) in Selenium Chrome. - The issue is still here.
3. I tried to update Chrome. - The issue is still here.
4. I tried to update Selenium. - The issue is still here.

A few interesting moments:

1. When I mouse over the place where DIV should be - it SHOWS!
2. When I try to check the height of the DIV with `$('.container').height()` - it SHOWS!
3. I tried to use Chrome launched by myself under Incognito mode. - No issue.

It looks like Chrome forgets to re-render the **DOM** or that element.